# Trying to roundoff a decimal to two digits in a xml nodevalue

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to remove the decimals and only print first two decimal values how can i do it.

xml

```
<bookstore>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>2.21595037861026842</price>
</bookstore>
```

how to print only first 2 decimal values from price tag

```
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0];
document.write(x.nodeValue);
```

result: 2.21

Comment: what programming language are you using? javascript/python/something else?

Comment: hi i am using javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0];
var z = x.nodeValue;
var y = Math.round(z * 100) / 100;
document.write(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, parse the node value string to float, then round the float to 2 decimal digits. Here is step-by-step example :

```
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0];
var string_x = x.nodeValue;
var float_x = parseFloat(string_x);
var float_x_fixed = float_x.toFixed(2);
document.write(float_x_fixed);
```

For reference :

- [`parseFloat(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)
- [`numObj.toFixed([digits])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: Thanku @har07. I am getting like this NAN. it is not parsing i hope

Comment: @user3124779 sorry, had a bit of typo, I have fixed that you could try again

Comment: @thank you har07. i got it by using Math.round(z * 100) / 100;